# Is there a way to generate Filestack's security token in React?

Tags: reactjs, filestack

I am trying to use `filestack`'s file picker in my React app. I have the API key, but when I am trying to run `getSecurity()` via the Frontend code, I am getting an error saying that this function get only be run in Node env.

Any suggestions how one can get security related token (`signature` & `policy`) via React.js code? without using a server

Thanks!